# For 10 values of x the mean is 86.2 and Σ(x − a) = 362 , find the value of

Tags: statistics

(i) Σ x,
(ii) the constant a.

Could you please kindly explain how to do it? I am really bad at math you see :P.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one you need to find the sum of $x$.
You have the mean already which is the sum divided by $10$. That should help for that part.

Now for the second part. We have the sum of $x-a$ which can be split into the sum of $x$ minus the sum of $a$ (ie 10 times a). You have the sum of $x$ from the first part so just set up a simple algebraic expression for this. Should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 1):

The average value is 86.2.

Average= Sum of observations/No. of observations.

Therefore, total sum, Σx= 10×86.2= 862

Σ(x-a)=Σx-a×n=862-10a=362,given
∴a=50.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: the mean of $x_1, x_2, \ldots x_{10}$ is defined as $\frac{x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_{10}}{10}$. Also, $\sum(x_i-a)=(x_1-a)+(x_2-a)+\ldots+(x_{10}-a)$ So, we can rearrange this as $(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_{10})-(a+a+\ldots+a)$. Can you take it from here?